# The Autocomplete component from Material-UI causes nothing to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an Autocomplete component returned inside the render method of a class. However, it causes nothing to render; taking the component out allows everything else to render as expected.

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {  
      return (
        ...
        <Row>
          <Autocomplete
            id="combo-box-demo"
            options={[{title: 'Inception'}, {title: 'Dark Knight'}]}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
            style={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={params => (
               <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
            )}
          />
        </Row>
      );
    }
  }
```

Taking out Autocomplete and everything inside allows the render to work normally. I am using the example Autocomplete code from Material-UI's guide.

I receive this error in the console:

*Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app*

What could be causing this render issue? What are the constraints on using Autocomplete(or hooks)?

Comment: Do you have any console errors on the page? Make sure you installed all the dependencies, autocomplete is not part of core

Comment: @Dellirium I should've checked that originally: yes there's console errors. I edited my post to include the error.

Comment: That code seems to work for me, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I did fix it recently; it was a problem with npm/dependencies. It involved running npm audit fix, but I don't understand exactly what the issue was haha. Thanks for suggesting the dependencies though. I spent way too long analyzing my code...

Answer (score -2):

Your code seems to work correctly.

Could you check the live demo that I have created down below?

Functional component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-rh82u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Class component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-material-ui-tmtoj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Your sandbox does work. However you use a function and then use "ReactDOM.render" with the function. I am using the Autocomplete within the render() of a class. Does this work? Or can I adapt my code to be more like your example? Thanks.

Comment: You can also use class component. I have made a sandbox for it as well. https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-material-ui-tmtoj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark